# Error in validation of choice for tic tac toe game

Tags: python, conditional-statements, runtime-error, tic-tac-toe, validationerror

This code asks the user for a pair of coordinates and then checks them against an array of valid coordinate pairs. If the user enters a pair that isn't valid, they are asked to re-enter them.

The code is returning an error in the return statement. Below is the code and the subsequent error.

```
def position_choice():
    '''the indexes are not yet given by the user so we initialise it with a string ,
    which can be anything'''
    x,y="not yet","not yet"
    #this contains the list of indexes that are in a tic tac  toe board
    ttt_index=[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
    #looping until we get the choice
    while (x.isdigit()==False and y.isdigit()==False) or[int(x),int(y)] not in ttt_index:
        x=(input("Which row would you like to place the element"))
        y=(input("Which column in the row would like to place the element"))
        if [int(x),int(y)] not in ttt_index:
            clear_output()
            print("I'm sorry the position that you've chosen is not valid, please do check and re-enter accordingly :)")
    return int(x,y)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/paul/Documents/k.py", line 16, in <module>
    position_choice()
  File "C:/Users/paul/Documents/k.py", line 14, in position_choice
    return int(x,y)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What is the error? There is no question

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted an edit pending approval which explains the problem that is occurring. The issue is how you are returning x and y. So change the return statement to: `return int(x), int(y)`